# Push user value to an existing array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I want to add a user inputted value to my array. Here's my code:

```
$('#checkoutButton').click(function () {
var array = new Array();
$("div #orderData").each(function () {
    var vals = $(this).find('input:hidden').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
        var bla = $('.cardQuantity').val(); //user inputted value

    array.push(bla,vals)
})
console.log(array);
});
```

But the result of this code is:

```
Array[2]
0:"6"
    1:Array[4]
        0:"200"
        1:"2500"
        2:"http:fb44.jpg?1715"
        3:"GCRDaK15"
```

But I just want to add the user inputted value on Array[4]. So my expected output would be:

```
         1:Array[4]
            0:"200"
            1:"2500"
            2:"http:fb44.jpg?1715"
            3:"GCRDaK15"
```

how would I do this? thanks

Comment: how about `vals.push(bla)`

Comment: Use `array = array.concat(vals); array.push(bla)`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande That will not help. To merge 2 arrays, you should use `array.concat`. Also `array.push(a,b)` is same as `array.push(a);array.push(b);`

Comment: @Rajesh thanks a lot for the info

Comment: hi @Rajesh, thank you for your correct answer. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var array = [];
 array.push([bla,vals]);
```

Comment: First `array` does not exist. Second, this in not the required answer. Please read question properly

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer for my problem:

```
vals.push(bla)
array.push(vals)
```